# .post().success() run when isSuccessStatusCode: false ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using ASP.NET Core Web API.

When using `return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);`

jQuery success() is being triggered even though I return an error status code.
The only way I can get .fail() to trigger is to throw an error.

Why does .success() run even though I am sending back an unsuccessful status code?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, according to https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4311, HttpResponseException has been completely removed in ASP.NET Core as we should not be using exceptions for control flow.

HttpResponseMessage will always return 200, no matter what error is returned in the response JSON.

A tutorial on how to implement custom error handling can be found here: http://www.talkingdotnet.com/global-exception-handling-in-aspnet-core-webapi/